# rails include CarrierWave::RMagick error in production server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave, rmagick

I want to use rmagick gem with carrier wave to upload and resize image.

in my Local Rails.. it works well.
but when deploy to server.. not works..

I don't know why T^T

here unicorn_error_log..

```
.../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require': No such file to load -- RMagick (LoadError)
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `block in require'
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:213:in `load_dependency'
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:228:in `require'
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:67:in `rescue in block in <module:RMagick>'
from ...p/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/processing/rmagick.rb:64:in `block in <module:RMagick>'
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `class_eval'
from .../shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/concern.rb:114:in `append_features'
from .../releases/20131018192701/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:5:in `include'
from .../releases/20131018192701/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:5:in `<class:ImageUploader>'
from .../releases/20131018192701/app/uploaders/image_uploader.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
```

but Curiously in server rails c production

```
a = Word.find(2)
a.image.recreate_versions!(:image, :thumb)
```

this works well no error!!!
thumb_~~.jpg , resized image generated..

and in server rails c production input

```
require 'RMagick'
=> false
```

this means RMagick is already loading , right?

Ah! this my image_uploader.rb

```
3: class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

5:    include CarrierWave::RMagick

52:   version :thumb do
53:      process :resize_to_limit => [400, 400]
54:   end
```

line 5 error!

for reference, i already finished below..

```
apt-get install libmagickwand-dev imagemagick
in Gemfile |  gem 'rmagick', :require => 'RMagick'
```

please help me..
why not work in server??

Comment: What is your production server setup?  Is RMagick installed there as well?

Comment: nginx + unicorn. yeah , rmagick installed well. in rails c production, rmagick method works well.

Comment: Is Rmagick in your production group in your Gemfile?

Answer (score 0):

How you are running server?

If your Gemfile have rmagick then you need to run server using bundle exec

Sometime dependency not loaded. bundle exec will make sure that dependency gets loaded always.

Comment: i deploy to server using capistrano. so 'bundle exec' whenever cap deploy T^T

Comment: How is your application server is running? what are you using for this app?